# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Incorrect syntax near 'CHARACTER'. 'utf8mb4' is not a recognized SET option

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am working on an ASP.Net Core 3.1 MVC project with EF Core and MySQL 8.0.31
I tried adding a new scaffolding item (Identity) to add custom personal data to a user. Then I created a new migration and after running `dotnet ef database update`, the error message in the title appears.

I've checked all files that include 'utf8mb4' and replaced them with 'utf8', but it gives me the same error, but 'utf8' instead. 'utf8mb4' *is* supported on my MySQL version last time I checked (today). I've also checked previous versions of the project and 'utf8mb4' was there in the migration files and I never encountered this error. I have searched extensively online for this problem in particular but I don't see many people having this same issue.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Detailed error message:

```
$ dotnet ef database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoles] (
          [Id] varchar(255) NOT NULL,
          [Name] varchar(256) NULL,
          [NormalizedName] varchar(256) NULL,
          [ConcurrencyStamp] longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      );
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoles] (
    [Id] varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    [Name] varchar(256) NULL,
    [NormalizedName] varchar(256) NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'CHARACTER'.
'utf8mb4' is not a recognized SET option.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:77d6b5ae-a86e-4883-bb36-214f6719f2f0
Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15
Incorrect syntax near 'CHARACTER'.
'utf8mb4' is not a recognized SET option.
```

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is for SQL Server, not for MySQL.

Comment: MySQL <> MS SQL aka SQL Server

Comment: @Evk Ah yes, it must have auto-generated when I scaffolded Identity. I changed it to the appropriate MySQL method. Thanks